# change date format function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, date

I am trying to change a date format, would you please help me out to change the date format into this Mon, 12 Feb 2016 11:00?

Here is the code below:

```
function nicetime(a, out) {
    var d = Math.round((+new Date - a) / 1000),
        fuzzy = '',
        n = 'mins',
        d = d < 0 ? 0 : d;
    if (out == 1) {
        return d;
    } else if (out == 0) {
        var chunks = new Array();
        chunks[0] = [60 * 60 * 24 * 365, 'year', 'years'];
        chunks[1] = [60 * 60 * 24 * 30, 'month', 'months'];
        chunks[2] = [60 * 60 * 24 * 7, 'week', 'weeks'];
        chunks[3] = [60 * 60 * 24, 'day', 'days'];
        chunks[4] = [60 * 60, 'hr', 'hrs'];
        chunks[5] = [60, 'min', 'mins'];
        var i = 0,
            j = chunks.length;
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            s = chunks[i][0];
            if ((xj = Math.floor(d / s)) != 0) {
                n = xj == 1 ? chunks[i][1] : chunks[i][2];
                break;
            }
        }
        fuzzy += xj == 1 ? '1 ' + n : xj + ' ' + n;
        if (i + 1 < j) {
            s2 = chunks[i + 1][0];
            if (((xj2 = Math.floor((d - (s * xj)) / s2)) != 0)) {
                n2 = (xj2 == 1) ? chunks[i + 1][1] : chunks[i + 1][2];
                fuzzy += (xj2 == 1) ? ' + 1 ' + n2 : ' + ' + xj2 + ' ' + n2;
            }
        }
        fuzzy += ' ago';
        return fuzzy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is your `a` and `out` ?

Comment: Please take the time to narrow you question down to something that is easier for people to understand what you want. Remove any code that is not necessary for the question.

Comment: You can try something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/snw738pq/)

Comment: [link]http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-social-stream/full_screen_preview/2201708 I am using this plugin

Comment: Cant we edit this code?

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose , your date is "February 04, 2011 19:00:00"**

```
function formatDate(date) {
 var d = new Date(date);
 var hh = d.getHours();
 var m = d.getMinutes();
 var s = d.getSeconds();
 var dd = "AM";
 var h = hh;
 if (h >= 12) {
    h = hh-12;
    dd = "PM";
 }
 if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
 }
 m = m<10?"0"+m:m;

 s = s<10?"0"+s:s;

/* if you want 2 digit hours:
 h = h<10?"0"+h:h; */

 var pattern = new RegExp("0?"+hh+":"+m+":"+s);

 var replacement = h+":"+m;
/* if you want to add seconds
 replacement += ":"+s;  */
 replacement += " "+dd;    

 return date.replace(pattern,replacement);
}

alert(formatDate("February 04, 2011 12:00:00"));
```